# how to add products to shopping cart using soap v2 api then checkout the products in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, soap, shopping-cart

When I add products to shopping cart using soap api v2 method i.e.
created cart using shoppingCartCreate and then adding products using shoppingCartProductAdd.
and then assigning this cart to customer using shoppingCartCustomerSet.
In response I get successfully added products to the cart but when i check it after logging into web view I found there is no product in the cart.

What's the reason for this?